# flutter length of nullable TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to read a nullable TextEditingController

```
  final TextEditingController? nameController = TextEditingController();

     if(nameController != null) {
       if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty && nameController.text.length >= 3) {
         ...
       }
     }
```

But get the error:

```
The property 'text' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. (Documentation)  Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you can use the `?.` operator. Use to access text so that if nameController has a null value, text cannot be accessed using this operator.

```
final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

if (nameController?.text?.isNotEmpty == true && nameController!.text.length >= 3) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: you already assign value to nameController so it will never null, better way is to remove ? from TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();